# Spring Security - Grails 3.2.2 - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: redirect, grails, spring-security, controller

I have this on my `application.yml`:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/l/loggedIn'
```

And the `l/loggedIn` looks like:

```
def loggedIn() {
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser

    def roleDefault = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_DEFAULT")
    if(user.authorities.contains(roleDefault))
        redirect(controller: 'foo', action:'index')

    def roleAdmin = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
    if(user.authorities.contains(roleAdmin))
        redirect(view: 'index')

}
```

When I log in as `admin`in my application I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Any way to fix this?

---

**Update**

```
@Secured(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_DEFAULT"])
class FooController {

    def index() {}
}
```

Comment: It happens only with admin user @AdeelAnsari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` doesn't take `view` in to account, `render` does.

Allowed options are, `action`, `controller`, `uri`, `url`, `params`, `fragment`, and/or a domain instance.

So, you can do something like,

```
def loggedIn() {
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser

    def roleDefault = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_DEFAULT")
    if(user.authorities.contains(roleDefault))
        redirect(controller: 'foo', action:'index')

    def roleAdmin = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
    if(user.authorities.contains(roleAdmin))
        redirect(controller: 'foo', action:'adminIndex')
}
```

then in your controller define both `actions`, with proper views available.

```
@Secured(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_DEFAULT"])
class FooController {

    def index() {}

    def adminIndex() {}

}
```

Read the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#redirectsAndChaining).

Comment: using redirect(uri: "/") solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped.